# What is the Weber class polynomial?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I came across the concept of the Weber class polynomial, and it is referenced back to Cox's book, "Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$". But as far as I searched there I didn't find anything there, except Weber functions. I think this concept should be something similar to Hilbert Class polynomial, but a little bit different.

Where can I find the precise definition? Could you please introduce a reference (not a research article), in which this concept is defined and explained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google helps: The [Weber class polynomials](https://www.math.uzh.ch/sepp/magma-2.25.2-ds/html/text1570.htm) are the "minimal polynomials of the Weber functions" (Cox, 2nd edition, p. 304).